# Рекурсия в php. Как работает?

Tags: php

Посоветуйте хорошую статью про рекурсия в php. Изучал ее в js, но в виду ненадобности как-то забыл про это, да и отличия я думаю какие-то есть.

Меня интересуют как можно больше подробностей, но главное чтобы была затронута тема про ограничения количества вызовов рекурсии.

Comment: Рекурсия как рекурсия, ограничена памятью и вот этим пресловутым Stack Overflow.

Comment: А что происходит когда стек переполняется? И какое это число?

Comment: программа завершается, а память высвобождается

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Рекурсивные функции**
>
> ```
> <?php
>     function recursion($a)
>     {
>         if ($a < 20) {
>             echo "$a\n";
>             recursion($a + 1);
>         }
>     }
> ?>
> ```
>
> **Замечание**: Рекурсивный вызов методов/процедур с глубиной **более 100-200** уровней рекурсии может вызвать переполнение стека и привести к
>   аварийному завершению скрипта. В частности, бесконечная рекурсия будет
>   считаться программной ошибкой.

Источник: [тык](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.user-defined.php)
 P.S: Пролистай до 4 примера.

Answer (score 1):

С точки зрения теории, мне больше всего понравилась жизненная метафора о рекурсии, когда берешь зеркало в свои руки и встаешь лицом к другому зеркалу. В итоге ты видишь в отражении себя с зеркалом, а в этом зеркале ещё одно отражение :)